# How to keep many specific strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with specific columns that looks like this:

```
colA    
['work', 'time', 'money', 'home', 'good', 'financial']    
['school', 'lazy', 'good', 'math', 'sad', 'important', 'dizzy', 'go']    
['frame', 'happy', 'feel', 'youth', 'change', 'home', 'past']    
['first', 'eat', 'good', 'hungry', 'empty', 'fool']    
['meet', 'risk', 'fire', 'angry', 'go']
```

ColA is string NOT list. And I have list like this:

```
word = ['good', 'sad', 'angry', 'feel', 'empty', 'dizzy', 'go', 'happy', 'fool', 'eat', 'past', 'lazy', 'youth', 'old', 'enjoy', 'free', 'time', 'hungry']
```

I want to keep the words in the list. So it should be look like this:

```
colA    
['time', 'good']    
['lazy', 'good', 'sad', 'dizzy', 'go']    
['happy', 'feel', 'youth', 'past']     
['eat', 'good', 'hungry', 'empty', 'fool']    
['angry, 'go']
```

I've tried using str.contains but getting an error:

```
contains() takes from 2 to 6 positional arguments but 18 were given
```

I'm just begginer, so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with list comprehension for filter matched values:

```
import ast

s = set(word)
df['new'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in ast.literal_eval(x) if y in s])
print (df)
                                                colA  \
0  ['work', 'time', 'money', 'home', 'good', 'fin...   
1  ['school', 'lazy', 'good', 'math', 'sad', 'imp...   
2  ['frame', 'happy', 'feel', 'youth', 'change', ...   
3  ['first', 'eat', 'good', 'hungry', 'empty', 'f...   
4        ['meet', 'risk', 'fire', 'angry', 'go']       

                                new  
0                      [time, good]  
1      [lazy, good, sad, dizzy, go]  
2        [happy, feel, youth, past]  
3  [eat, good, hungry, empty, fool]  
4                       [angry, go]
```

**Performance comparison:** With this data `apply` is faster like pure list comprehension:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [26]: %timeit df['colB'] = [[w for w in literal_eval(l) if w in S] for l in df['colA']]
845 ms ± 32.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [27]: %timeit df['new'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in ast.literal_eval(x) if y in s])
826 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Not sure how you ran the timings, but I get radically different results

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval##) in a list comprehension (faster than `apply`):

```
from ast import literal_eval

# using a set for efficiency (for x in LIST is slow)
S = set(word)

df['colA'] = [str([w for w in literal_eval(l) if w in S]) for l in df['colA']]
```

*NB. the output here is a **string**, if you want a list use: `df['colA'] = [[w for w in literal_eval(l) if w in S] for l in df['colA']]`.*

output:

```
                                     colA
0                        ['time', 'good']
1  ['lazy', 'good', 'sad', 'dizzy', 'go']
2      ['happy', 'feel', 'youth', 'past']
3        ['eat', 'good', 'empty', 'fool']
4                         ['angry', 'go']
```

##### timing

the list comprehension is significantly faster than `apply` (tested on pandas 1.5)

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
df['new'] = [[w for w in literal_eval(l) if w in S] for l in df['colA']]
674 ms ± 69.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df['new'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in literal_eval(x) if y in s])
1.04 s ± 67.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: hmmm, interesting, maybe difference is version of pandas?

Comment: @jezrael I used 1.5, so I guess the conclusion is rather `apply` is slower, or similar to a list comprehension, depending on the version. From a theoretical point of view I don't see how a pandas loop could be marginally faster than q list comprehension.

Comment: maybe you mean df['colB'] = , btw it worked, thank you!

Comment: @andryan86 you can assign to any column you want, same or new ;)